# Simultaneous custom animation using CSS 3 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jQuery and CSS 3 and have been digging up CSS 3 a lot in my free time. I have this small testimonials animation that I would really like to work in a certain way, but unfortunately I am unable to get the CSS and jQuery to behave exactly as I want it to.

Here's what I have done so far: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgfpwwfw/).

What I want to achieve:

Now when I click on the `<li>`, what I basically want is the current text in the `<div class="says"></div>`to move downwards and the new text (basically text stored in the data-says on the clicked li) to transition in. Both of this should happen simultaneously.

My code so far looks like this, CSS:

```
// custom animation for sliding in new content
keyframes rotate{
    0%{
        transform:rotateX(20deg) translateY(-20px);
        /*transform: translateX(100px);*/
        text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5),
                    1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);;
    }
    100%{
        transform:rotateX(0deg) translateX(0px);
        text-shadow:none;
    }
}

.animated{
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
    -o-animation-name: rotate;
    animation-name: rotate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.35s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1.35s;
    animation-duration: 1.35s;
}

// custome animation for downward slide 
@keyframes movedown{
    0%{
        transform:rotateX(0) translateY(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform:rotateX(-30deg) translateY(20px);
    }
} 


.moved{
    -webkit-animation-name: movedown;
    -o-animation-name: movedown;
    animation-name: movedown;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Now the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('ul').on('click', 'li', function () {

                    $('.says').removeClass('moved animated');

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.says').addClass('moved');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            // $('.says').html('')
                        }, 1500)    
                    }, 100);

                    $this = $(this);

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var _stor = $this.data('says');
                        $('.says').removeClass('animated');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('.says') .html(_stor).addClass('animated');
                        },100)

                    }, 700)

                });
            });
```

Basically in the jQuery code I am attaching a eventhandler to the `<ul>` tag and after that I am basically targeting the `<div class="say"></div>` to remove and update the content, but notice 1 things.

The two setTimeout function (forget the internal setTimeout function), both function separately, ie. the 1st setTimeout function removes the current text from the div with a transition and then the 2nd setTimeout function transitions the new text, but both functions are functioning separately rather then simultaneously. I have no idea how I can get these two transitions to work simultaneously.

By simultaneously, I mean the following:

[image: Simultaneous animation]

Comment: You can't really make these functions to execute "simultaneously." [Check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67yzzn4m/4/). In javascript / jquery, you can queue up events to fire as soon as the "event loop" is free, but you can't fire functions off simultaneously. However, from your example, it looks like you really are just looking for the text to transition smoothly in and out - is this correct?

Comment: @wahwahwah yeah exactly ! thats all i'am looking for . but they should transition simultaniously !

Comment: @wahwahwah i guess setTimeout can't be used to acheive what i want to acheive ! , what other approach can i use then ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `setTimeout()` to get where you want to go, but I'm not sure it's necessary. In fact, using your example, just by changing the timing it looks a lot more like [what I think you want](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgfpwwfw/3/)... There are many ways to skin a cat, though. Do you want to try to accomplish this using mostly css3? What *exactly* do you want the animation to look like in the end?

Comment: @wahwahwah , i added an image ! that should explain what i want . i actually used set Timeout as a temporary code , i kind of knew there is no way of running 2 set Timeouts simultaneously . ur fiddle is doing the same as waht was initially there , what have u changed ? . Thanks for ur help though !

Comment: All I changed was the timeout speeds to make it a little less jumpy. If you take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgfpwwfw/6/) I think this is more along the lines of what you are looking for? Let me know if this is what you want and I'll post all this stuff as an answer :)

Comment: @wahwahwah you can post an answer no problem . but see the image , in transition out is visible while the transition in is also visible at some point of the animation , but in ur fiddle , the transition fade's out and the transition in fades in , its still not simultanious , its still not in synch .

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to cover a few topics in response - for posterity, and hopefully some educational benefit - before actually pulling this together in an example that fits the specific needs of your post.

### Simultaneous Execution of JavaScript & jQuery functions

Technically, it's not possible to execute JavaScript functions simultaneously - or asynchronously. All JavaScript code is executed in on a single thread in an `event loop`. However, it is possible to queue up actions that won't take place until after the event loop is available again.

***Code Snippet Example***:

```js
/// Open your console and then click "Run" within jsFiddle
// Illustration of how the 'event loop' handles executing functions
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("starting...");
  setTimeout(runAsync, 0); //Async?
  console.log("ending...")
});

function runAsync() {
  console.log("...running Async... now!");
}

//"starting..."
//"ending..."
//"...running Async... now!"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's not really *async* - rather deferred execution. Deferring can be used, however, in conjunction with `css` to give the *appearance* of simultaneous actions occurring.

### Mocking Simultaneous Execution of Functions With JQuery

A very easy way to create the appearance of simultaneous functions is through the use of JQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Since, part of the goal of the OP was to utilize CSS3 (and to learn while solving a problem) - an example that leans more on css, less on `.animate()`, and actually answers the OP is included later. In the meantime, here is a "simultaneous" example using `.animate()`:

***JQuery .animate() Example***:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    console.log("--- START ---");
    console.log("Animate One...");

    $("#one").animate({
      left: "+=300",
      top: "+=300",
      opacity: 0.25
    }, "slow", function() { // <-- callback
      console.log("Animate One Callback...");
    });

    console.log("Animate Two...");

    $("#two").animate({
      left: "+=10",
      top: "+=20",
      fontSize: "50px"
    }, "slow", function() { // <-- callback
      console.log("Animate Two Callback...");
    });
  });
});

// --- START ---
// Animate One...
// Animate Two...
// Animate One Callback...
// Animate Two Callback...
```

```css
#go {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}
.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: grey;
}
#one {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">GO</button>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```

You'll notice from the console log that the `.animate()` callback functions were delegated to the end of the event loop - similar to `setTimeout()`.

There's also another useful jQuery function, [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), that allows you to manipulate the event loop. Combined with the CSS3 being utilized in the OP, `.queue()` offers a slightly cleaner alternative to `setTimeout()` that also enables you to give the appearance of simultaneous functions.

### ANSWER(!!!): Using jQuery .queue() and CSS3 Instead of jQuery .animate()

Please see comments in code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {

    // Get the current visible element
    var curElem = $('.content');

    // Reset the class assignment if not first time li is clicked
    curElem.removeClass('moved animated');

    // Clone the original element, set it to "no display"
    // Make sure it's behind the original when both visible

    var cloneElem = curElem.clone();
    cloneElem.css({
      "z-index": "-1",
      "display": "none"
    });


    // Get new text for Clone
    // Fill the Clone with text, add it to the container div

    $this = $(this);
    var _stor = $this.data('says');
    cloneElem.find('.says').html(_stor);
    cloneElem.appendTo('#info-container');

    // Queue and delay functions similarly to setInterval - but is 
    // slightly easier to read/write/comprehend
    // fiddling with the "delay" and "fade" function numbers will change effect

    curElem.addClass('moved').delay(1500).queue(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(800).remove().dequeue(); // Remove original element
    });

    cloneElem.addClass('animated').delay(100).queue(function() {
      $(this).fadeIn(200).css("z-index", "").dequeue();
    });

  });
});
```

```css
/* ~~~ START additional styles ~~~ */

/* ADDED - needed parent element with 
relative positioning in order for child element to
move as expected */

#info-container {
  border: solid 2px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 250px;
  z-index: -2;
}

/* ADDED - basically .says 
but with asbolute positioning
*/

.content {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: -400px;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
}

/* Also changed later -- translateY() in movedown, rotate
was difficult to see "simultaneous" effect without - please tweak if needed
*/
/* ~~~ END addtional styles ~~*/

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
img {
  max-height: 36px;
  max-width: hidden;
}
/*styles for link-holder*/

.link-holder {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.link-holder li {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  display: table;
  text-align: left;
}
.link-holder li img {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.link-holder li p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.link-holder li p {
  margin: 0 0 0px 0;
}
/* end of styles for link-holder*/

/*animation styles*/

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(20deg) translateY(-150px);
    /*transform: rotateX(20deg) translateY(-20px);*/
    /* <--- INCREASE translateY to make scroll in effects more prounouced"
    /*transform: translateX(100px);*/
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    ;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateX(0px);
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes movedown {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0) translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-10deg) translateY(150px);
    /* transform: rotateX(-10deg) translateY(20px);*/
    /* <---- INCREASE translateY to make "scroll out effect" more pronounced */
  }
}
.moved {
  -webkit-animation-name: movedown;
  -o-animation-name: movedown;
  animation-name: movedown;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.35s;
  -o-animation-duration: 1.35s;
  animation-duration: 1.35s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.450, 0.395, 0.220, 1);
  /* older webkit */
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.450, 0.395, 0.220, 1.210);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.450, 0.395, 0.220, 1.210);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.450, 0.395, 0.220, 1.210);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.450, 0.395, 0.220, 1.210);
  /* custom */
}
/*end of animation styles*/
```

```html
<!-- 

ADDED:

two divs - info-container, content
the 'says' <p> in the OP was doing double duty,
holding association to css formatting and containing text to be replaced

added two container divs to make it easier to copy / swap out without
breaking the css

!-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="testimonials" class="testimo">
  <div>
    <div id="info-container">
      <div class="content">
        <p class="says">stock ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="link-holder clearfix">
      <li data-says="stock ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">
        <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/round/button_round_seagreen.png" alt="">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum
          <br><small>Stock Broker</small>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li data-says="Angel ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">
        <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/round/button_round_seagreen.png" alt="">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum
          <br><small>Angel investor</small>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li data-says="Client ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">
        <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/round/button_round_seagreen.png" alt="">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum
          <br><small>Client</small>
        </p>
      </li>
      <li data-says="Developer ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.">
        <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/blanks/buttons/round/button_round_seagreen.png" alt="">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum
          <br><small>Developer</small>
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ! thanks a ton , i'll go through ur answer , once i am home .